# Is it possible to pass props by match in React Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-link

I am passing props to the same component in two different ways.

Once by Route path:-

```
<Route path="/CreateProfile/:title" exact component={ProfileForm} />
```

Another by Link as:

```
<Table.Cell><Link to={{  // it will land to the same component ProfileForm
pathname:  "/EditProfile",
props: {
profile : profile,
title: "Edit Profile" 
}
}} >Edit Profile</Link></Table.Cell>
```

In my ProfileForm, I tried to read props as:-

```
useEffect(() => {

  if(props.match.params.title){ // it gives no error. 
    setTitle(props.match.params.title);
  }else if(props.location.props.title){ // gives error .props.title undefiened 
    setTitle(props.location.props.title);
  }
  // if(props.match.params.profile){
  //   setProfile(props.location.state.profile)
  // }
  if(props.location.props.profile){
    setProfile(props.location.props.profile)
    console.log("profile: "+props.location.props.profile)
  }
}
```

`else if(props.location.props.title)` gives an error when it comes from the Router. It is expected because I set props by Link. I noticed `props.match.params.title` never gives any error whether it is set or not. So I wish to pass props by the match from Link so that both Route and Link works properly.
Is it possible to pass props by match? Or how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure about the Link fragment? Your link to prop has `pathname:  "/EditProfile"`, but your Route has `/CreateProfile` pathname!

Comment: I have also another Route as `<Route path="/EditProfile" exact component={ProfileForm} />`. So both /CreateProfile and //EditProfile points to the same component. Once I create a new profile and another time I allow to edit an existing profile.

Comment: Would you please provide a better example of your code? Because you can pass the challenge with different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data via the pathname (URL), i.e. via url match or query parameters, or via route state.

[Link to-object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link/to-object)

> An object that can have any of the following properties:
>
> - **pathname: A string representing the path to link to.**
> - **search: A string representation of query parameters.**
> - hash: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.
> - **state: State to persist to the location.**

You clearly have your route setup for the *pathname* variant with a route param of `title`.

```
"/CreateProfile/:title"
```

You should simply construct your link to have the correct `title` value built into it.

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/CreateProfile/<some title value>" }} >
  Create Profile
</Link>
```

From here you need only access the route's `match.params.title` as you've correctly done.

**Now**, in the case of the edit profile route, `"/EditProfile"` there is, OFC, no route match param (and no query parameters), so the correct way is to use route state.

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/EditProfile",
    state: {
      profile,
      title: 'Edit Title',
    },
  }}
>
  Edit Profile
</Link>
```

And correctly access route state from the `history` object

```
useEffect(() => {
  const { history, match } = props;

  if (match.params.title) { 
    setTitle(match.params.title);
  } else if (history.location.state.title){
    setTitle(history.location.state.title);
  }

  if (history.location.state.profile) {
    setProfile(history.location.state.profile)
    console.log("profile: ", history.location.state.profile)
  }
}
```

Word of advice about the route state however, the object path isn't always guaranteed to exist (i.e. be defined) from `props.history.location` to the ultimate value you are accessing, so guard are necessary to prevent "access blah of undefined" errors.

```
 // state may not be defined depending on which route the app took to get to the page
history.location.state && history.location.state.title
```